# If $f(x)$ is continuous in [0,1] such that $f(x)+f(x+1/2)=5$, then find $\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is my attempt

$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx+\int_{1/2}^{1}f(x)dx$

$\int_{1/2}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{1/2}^1 5-f(x-1/2)$

Assume that $\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx=[F(x)]_0^{1/2}=F(1/2)-F(0)$

Similarly we can say that $\int_{1/2}^1 5-f(x-1/2)=[5x-F(x-1/2)]_{1/2}^{1}=5(1/2)-F(1/2)+F(0)$ using the property "If $\int f(x)=F(x)+c,\int f(x+b)=F(x+b)+c$"

$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx+\int_{1/2}^{1}f(x)dx=5/2=2.5$

But the answer is 6 :(. Where am I going wrong? Or is the answer wrong

Comment: I'm getting $5/2$. The answer is wrong. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/2}(5-f(x+{1\over 2}))dx$$ $$=5/2-\int_{1\over 2}^{1}f(x)dx$$

So $$\int_0^{1}f(x)dx=5/2$$